# Android Java - are floats ever automatically represented with a comma instead of period in Europe and other countries

Tags: java, android, internationalization, floating-point

The European convention for decimals seems to use a comma (,) instead of a period (.). Does this mean that floats might (**automatically**) come up as "3,1415..." in the EU and other countries where this is the convention?

That is... if I made a call to `Float.toString(motionEvent.getX())`, I might get 215,35 instead of 215.35 (somewhere in the middle of the screen)?

Comment: How are you formatting them, i.e. what code are you using?

Comment: updated with a snippet.. wondering if android java would show floats differently, since i am planning to string parse

Comment: I would be very surprised if it did (when using `Float.toString`). Have you tried it? (That should be easy enough to do...)

Answer (score 3):

[`Float.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29) doesn't use the culture, no - the format is fixed. See the documentation for the details, including:

> If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10n ≤ m < 10n+1; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).
>   How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as m

It *would* use a comma if you use things like [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with the default settings for a European locale.

Comment: in other words, the . is given preference over the ,?

Comment: @ina: Not for `Float.toString`, no. This is why the code you're using is such an important part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is "locale" (in how the textual representation of a float is printed out, not the value of the float itself).

Yes, AFAIK, European locales support "," instead of ".":

> - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html
>
> A common mistake is to implicitly use the default locale when
>   producing output meant to be machine-readable. This tends to work on
>   the developer's test devices (especially because so many developers
>   use en_US), but fails when run on a device whose user is in a more
>   complex locale.
>
> For example, if you're formatting integers some locales will use
>   non-ASCII decimal digits. As another example, if you're formatting
>   floating-point numbers some locales will use ',' as the decimal point
>   and '.' for digit grouping. That's correct for human-readable output,
>   but likely to cause problems if presented to another computer
>   (parseDouble(String) can't parse such a number, for example). You
>   should also be wary of the toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() overloads
>   that don't take a Locale

ADDENDUM:

In other words, some APIs are locale-aware, and others aren't.  A nasty side effect is that some code might *appear* to work correctly on a handset that happens to be configured for one locale, and fail (or even crash!) on a handset configured for a different locale.

The trick is to be aware of the issue, and familiar with which APIs are, and aren't, locale-aware.

The example in question, "Float.toString()", *isn't*.

Comment: That's fine if you're using a locale-sensitive formatter - but `Float.toString` isn't locale-sensitive.

Comment: To suppport Jon, see "To create localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of NumberFormat." at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html

Comment: True - I stand corrected :)  "Float.toString()" is *NOT* locale-aware, "String.format()" *IS*: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html.  Among other locale-aware alternatives.